# why are my dropdown is not showing in laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

This is my playingcards-advance (view page):

```
<h5>Country:</h5>
<select class="productcategory put" id="prod_cat_id">

    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
    @foreach($prod as $cat)
        <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->product_cat_name}}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>
<h5>State:</h5>
<select class="productname put">

    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select State</option>
</select>
<h5>City:</h5>
<select class="city put">

    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Select City</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('change', '.productcategory', function () {
            // console.log("hmm its change");

            var cat_id = $(this).val();
            // console.log(cat_id);
            var div = $(this).parent();

            var op = " ";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{!!URL::to('findProductName')!!}',
                data: {'id': cat_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log('success');

                    //console.log(data);

                    //console.log(data.length);
                    op += '<option value="0" selected disabled>Select City</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        op += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].productname + '</option>';
                    }

                    div.find('.productname').html(" ");
                    div.find('.productname').append(op);
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('change', '.productname', function () {
            var prod_id = $(this).val();

            var a = $(this).parent();
            console.log(prod_id);
            var op = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{!!URL::to('findcity')!!}',
                data: {'id': prod_id},
                dataType: 'json',//return data will be json
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');

                    console.log(data);
                    op += '<option value="0" selected disabled>choose city</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        op += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].city + '</option>';
                    }

                    a.find('.city').html(" ");
                    a.find('.city').append(op);


                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });


        });

    });
</script>
```

This is my Route code:

```
Route::get('/playingcards-advance', 'PagesController@prodfunct');
Route::get('/findProductName', 'PagesController@findProductName');
Route::get('/findPrice', 'PagesController@findPrice');
Route::get('/findcity', 'PagesController@findcity');
```

This is PagesController code

```
public function prodfunct()
{
    $prod = ProductCat::all();//get data from table
    return view('playingcards-advance', compact('prod'));//sent data to view

}

public function findProductName(Request $request)
{
    //if our chosen id and products table prod_cat_id col match the get first 100 data 

    //$request->id here is the id of our chosen option id
    $data = Product::select('productname', 'id')->where('prod_cat_id', $request->id)->take(100)->get();

    return response()->json($data);//then sent this data to ajax success
}

public function findcity(Request $request)
{
    //if our chosen id and products table prod_cat_id col match the get first 100 data 

    //$request->id here is the id of our chosen option id
    $q = City::select('city', 'id')->where('state_id', $request->id)->take(100)->get();

    return response()->json($q);//then sent this data to ajax success
}
```

The problem is that I'm not able to display state and city but I'm able to display country
I have also made model of all table
why it is not displaying state and city in the code
when I click on console and try to select country as America it is giving this error GET http://localhost/tmcards2/public/findProductName?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

The problem is that I'm not able to display state and city but I'm able to display country
I have also made model of all table
why it is not displaying state and city in the code
when I click on console and try to select country as America it is giving this error GET http://localhost/tmcards2/public/findProductName?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
The problem is that I'm not able to display state and city but I'm able to display country
I have also made model of all table
why it is not displaying state and city in the code
when I click on console and try to select country as America it is giving this error GET http://localhost/tmcards2/public/findProductName?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
why it is not displaying state and city in the code
when I click on console and try to select country as America it is giving this error GET http://localhost/tmcards2/public/findProductName?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Let's start by code formatting.

Comment: are you sure  http://localhost/tmcards2/public/findProductName?id=1 is right url? could you run this url manually in browser?

Comment: @Mohammadb   0: productname "Uttarpradesh" id: 1

Comment: Why you have mixed ProductCategory, Country, States, City etc....?